# Only allow the body to scroll x pixels css

Tags: html, css

Lets say my website is 2000px long, my viewport is 1000px tall like so:

[image]

By default this will allow the website to scroll 1000px. In order to scroll that distance the scroll bar must move from the top to the bottom.

However what if I only want the scroll bar to be able to scroll 500px, thus hiding the bottom 500px of the website, but I don't want to change the height of my website.

I tried to do this using the css code below:

```
body{
    height: 1500px;
    max-height: 1500px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

But this didn't work because body doesn't have a parent element to add scroll bars around it.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to have part of the page like this not be visible? Also, `body` does have a parent element: `html`.

Comment: @TylerH That worked, thank you I set the html element to overflow scroll. It's for a javascript plugin I'm trying out, I want to bind scroll distance to a javascript event.

Comment: Glad to hear that worked; please add your solution as an answer and give it the checkmark so others know what solved it for you!

Comment: Not sure if this has been solved or not, if not then why not just put it in a div that has a max-height of 1500px (allows the body to scroll to 1500px) with `overflow:hidden`  I also don't see why you would do this as it is a massive usability issue and is likely to result in a high bounce rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion in the comments I realized the html element is the parent of the body element. Thus using the css code in my answer and setting the html overflow to scroll everything works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I believe position should be relative not absolute. Do you need it to be the body element? Why not create a container element and just wrap the pages content in that so it would be

Example

```
<body>
<div class="main-container">
website content
</div>
</body>
```

Styling:

```
.main-container {
height: 1500px;
max-height: 1500px;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: I tried position relative, but it didn't work either. I want to do it on the body because I am developing a javascript plugin that needs to work on as many websites as possible, so I won't be able to wrap a websites elements in a parent div ahead of time